# Upgrade to Exchange 2010 broke ability to save attachments in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, attachments, exchange-2010

Our University upgraded to Exchange 2010 server.  And one of our users lost the ability to save attachments (via a save dialog) from anyone outside the institution.  If she chooses save attachments, nothing happens.  But if it is from someone in the institution, it works.  The behavior seems to be independent of the attachment type .  I tried creating a fresh profile and it made no difference.  She can drag from the email to her desktop and it works, but she would like to be able to use the save dialog for external attachments as she can with attachments sent internally.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: How are they trying to save attachments?  With the "Save all attachments" button, or by right-clicking each attachment and saving, or some other way?

Comment: I am sorry, a miscommunication happened.  She has office 2007 not 2010.  I found a patch kb2276479.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue for Outlook 2007 (and 2003), but not 2010.

If it is Outlook 2007, then Outlook 2007 SP2 + the Hotfix available in [MS KB2276479](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2276479) should take care of it.

> Under **Issues that this hotfix package fixes**:
>
> Consider the following scenario:
>
> - Your mailbox is moved to Microsoft Exchange Server 2010.
> - In Office Outlook 2007, you open an email message that contains an attachment.
> - The message was sent by an external user.
> - You click the Microsoft Office button, point to Save As, and then click Save Attachments.
>
> In this scenario, the attachment is not saved as expected.

Comment: yes I found it and was in the process of fixing the question when you posted your answer.

Comment: Cool, hopefully it'll make your pain stop (for now ;) ).